# Upgrading to HTML5, what about HGROUP?

Tags: html, header

So I was about 40% of completion of my new template when I decided to move towards HTML5 :) So I have the header, navigation, and footer completed.  I was getting ready to work on the index.php file when I noticed an article on HGROUP.

This is my header:

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapped">
        <a href="#" id="logo"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <nav>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Main Navigation')); ?>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

The wrapped is the part that keeps it set to center with margin: 0 auto; and sets the width of 990px.  Should I be using HGROUP for my logo, or is it completely done with nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HGROUP is done away with as of earlier this year, see:

- http://html5doctor.com/the-hgroup-element/
- http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-admin/2013Apr/0003.html

Answer (score 1):

[`hgroup` has been dropped from the HTML5 spec](http://www.webmonkey.com/2013/04/w3c-drops-hgroup-tag-from-html5-spec/), so avoid using it, as browsers will likely fully remove support for it in the future. Just using a `div` should be fine, adding a `class` if relevant.